# UIScrollView doesn't scroll. What's wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have created a `scroll(width 320, height 420)` in 'Interface Builder'.

and in class:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1000)];
 }
```

but the scroll view is not scrolling?

See the print screens

```
   http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/scrollo.png 
  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/203/capturadetela20121103s2.png 
  http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/889/capturadetela20121103s2.png
```

Comment: did you bind the IBOutlet with the 'interface builder'?

Comment: Yes, I did bind the IBOutlet with the Interface Builder

Comment: Make sure 'User Interaction Enabled' is ticked in IB

Comment: Yes, User interaction is enabled and multiple touch disabled

Comment: Are you sure that your objects are on the scroll view rather then the original UIView?

Comment: yes :( they are in scroll view

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/scrollo.png/

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/203/capturadetela20121103s2.png/

Comment: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/889/capturadetela20121103s2.png

Comment: Show a picture with your scroll view opened.  This only shows a scroll view above two image views.

Comment: Do you have other `uiviews` in your `scrollView`?

Comment: No, only two buttons and one textview

Comment: Maybe it's because the ios 6 has constraints.. or no?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you have not successfully added the images or have not successfully set the scrollView's contentSize. And I suggest you to set the contentSize after you add the image view to your scrollView. `viewDidLoad` is good idea. Most of the time don't do much work in `viewWillAppear`. The view will not be shown until this method finish.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you init with your scrollView with frame:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 360)];
```

Remember also to set contentSize bigger than frame, for example:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2*280, 360);
```

Also add delegate in your interface:

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

And delegate it:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: have you check scroll enabled in Xib

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: "Auto layout" was on ... must to be off.